# MySQL column have null value but "is null" is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mySQL table and have column which have null and not null data.

While running query and visibly i can see that BLOCKER column have null values.

```
mysql> select count(1), BLOCKER from mysql.PRSSTATE group by BLOCKER;
+----------+----------------+
| count(1) | BLOCKER        |
+----------+----------------+
|   193403 |                | 
|      350 | Beta           | 
|       24 | Build          |
```

If i issue query as shown below i am getting count(1) as zero.

```
mysql> select count(1) from mysql.PRSSTATE where BLOCKER  is NULL;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|        0 | 
+----------+
1 row in set (0.13 sec)
```

My doubt is that it might have special character as i have migrated the data from some other system into this table. Wondering how to resolve this. It should be showing by "is null" statement.

Comment: It's an empty string, not a null value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BLOCKER` may be has zero length:

```
select count(1) from mysql.PRSSTATE where (BLOCKER  is NULL or BLOCKER = "");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you incorrectly assume that BLOCKER is NULL. In fact you are storing empty strings ("") and not a NULL value. You should modify your query to match both NULL and "" values:

```
select count(1) from mysql.PRSSTATE where BLOCKER IS NULL OR BLOCKER = "";
```

Alternatively modify your script (or whatever you've used to create those records) to insert NULL value when you have no data for the BLOCKER column or just don't pass anything and make sure that your BLOCKER column's definition is set to DEFAULT NULL.

If BLOCKER was NULL you would get the following output from your first query:

```
+----------+----------------+
| count(1) | BLOCKER        |
+----------+----------------+
|   193403 | NULL           | 
|      350 | Beta           | 
|       24 | Build          | 
+----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for date fields many IDEs will show `null` when it's actually an empty string ('') or zero (0). You can usually test for all with ISNULL:

```
WHERE ISNULL(`yourDate`, 0) = 0
```

Comment: Can "date fields" actually be an "empty string" or "zero"?

Comment: In MySQL, yes. I believe 0 is a valid data in most systems because the engine sets it to start-of-epoch (1900-01-01).